# JSONB column creates audit entry when no changes have been made even on select

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jsonb, hibernate-envers

I am pretty new to this subject, so this could be something I am missing, but I am facing a problem with Hibernate Envers in which JSONB columns cause audit entries to be added even if no changes have been made to the content of the column and even if I am only doing a select.

Not doing anything particularly special here, just have a web service with a controller, service, repository (Paging & Sorting), and a DTO to convert the internal entity to a client-facing entity.

My config is:

- PostgreSQL 10
- Spring Boot Web + JPA + Hibernate + Envers
- Using vladmihalcea hibernate types, JsonBinaryType

Example code:

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_sometable",schema="public")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class SomeObject{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private UUID id;

    @NonNull
    @SomeColumnConstraint
    @Type(type="jsonb")
    @Column(name="someColumnName", columnDefinition="jsonb")
    private Map<String,Object> configItemValue = new HashMap<String,Object>();

}
```

I am using Envers without column-level auditing, but I have switched column-level on, and I can then see that the only columns with "true" in the _MOD columns are JSONB - and this is set for ALL JSONB columns.  None of the other non-JSONB columns are set to "true".

When I set the JSONB columns to @NotAudited no audit entry is created on select.

I have tried creating a custom Dialect but this did not resolve the issue.

To work around this I have set all my JSONB columns to @NotAudited and am ensuring that on every update to an entity I set a LastUpdatedDate to ensure that I get an audit entry, so ultimately this is not going to cause me an issue in my app, but this appears to be a bug.

Would like to know if anyone else has come across this issue and if they've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value is considered dirty/unequal to the original value. Maybe there is a bug some equality method somewhere. You can start debugging here: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/blob/master/hibernate-types-5/src/main/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/type/json/internal/JsonTypeDescriptor.java#L76